# How to Implement UnifiedNative ads in Xamarin.Forms ios

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, unifiednativeadview

I am trying to add UnifiedNative ads in my xamarin.forms Application. I successfully implemented them in Android but having a hard time for iOS.

For Android - I have created a custom renderer and a xml layout for holding the Ad content.

For ios, I tried to follow this - github.com/xamarin/GoogleApisForiOSComponents/blob/master/docs/Firebase/AdMob/ but it is not very clear and provides help only in Swift/Objective C and I am looking for C#.

EDIT -

Xamarin.Forms

in .xaml

```
 <adview:AdmobNativeAd HeightRequest="360"></adview:AdmobNativeAd>
```

AdView class -

```
 public class AdmobNativeAd : ContentView
    {
        public AdmobNativeAd()
        {
            this.HeightRequest = 360;
            this.Margin = new Thickness(8, 8, 8, 0);

            SetPlaceholderContent();
        }

        private void SetPlaceholderContent()
        {
            var placeholderGrid = new Grid();
            var placeHolderText = new Label
            {
                Text = "AD",
                FontSize = 48,
                FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold,
                TextColor = Color.White,
                Opacity = 0.3,
                VerticalOptions = new LayoutOptions(LayoutAlignment.Center, true),
                HorizontalOptions = new LayoutOptions(LayoutAlignment.Center, true)
            };

            placeholderGrid.Children.Add(placeHolderText);

            this.Content = placeholderGrid;
        }

    }
```

Android Implementation -

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(AdmobNativeAd), typeof(xxx.Droid.Services.NativeAd))]
namespace xxx.Droid.Services
{
    public class NativeAd : ViewRenderer
    {

        public NativeAd(Context context) : base(context) { }
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.View> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control == null)
            {
                var adLoader = new AdLoader.Builder(Context, "ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxx");

                var listener = new UnifiedNativeAdLoadedListener();
                listener.OnNativeAdLoaded += (s, ad) =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        var root = new UnifiedNativeAdView(Context);
                        var inflater = (LayoutInflater)Context.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService);
                        var adView = (UnifiedNativeAdView)inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.ad_unified, root);

                        populateUnifiedNativeAdView(ad, adView);

                        SetNativeControl(adView);
                    }
                    catch
                    {

                    }
                };

                adLoader.ForUnifiedNativeAd(listener);
                var requestBuilder = new AdRequest.Builder();
                adLoader.Build().LoadAd(requestBuilder.Build());
            }
        }

        private void populateUnifiedNativeAdView(UnifiedNativeAd nativeAd, UnifiedNativeAdView adView)
        {
            adView.MediaView = adView.FindViewById<MediaView>(Resource.Id.ad_media);

            // Set other ad assets.
            adView.HeadlineView = adView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.ad_headline);
            adView.BodyView = adView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.ad_body);
            adView.CallToActionView = adView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.ad_call_to_action);
            adView.IconView = adView.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.ad_app_icon);
            adView.PriceView = adView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.ad_price);
            adView.StarRatingView = adView.FindViewById<RatingBar>(Resource.Id.ad_stars);
            adView.StoreView = adView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.ad_store);
            adView.AdvertiserView = adView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.ad_advertiser);

            // The headline and mediaContent are guaranteed to be in every UnifiedNativeAd.
            ((TextView)adView.HeadlineView).Text = nativeAd.Headline;

            // These assets aren't guaranteed to be in every UnifiedNativeAd, so it's important to
            // check before trying to display them.
            if (nativeAd.Body == null)
            {
                adView.BodyView.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;
            }
            else
            {
                adView.BodyView.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
                ((TextView)adView.BodyView).Text = nativeAd.Body;
            }

            if (nativeAd.CallToAction == null)
            {
                adView.CallToActionView.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;
            }
            else
            {
                adView.CallToActionView.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
                ((Android.Widget.Button)adView.CallToActionView).Text = nativeAd.CallToAction;
            }

            if (nativeAd.Icon == null)
            {
                adView.IconView.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
            }
            else
            {
                ((ImageView)adView.IconView).SetImageDrawable(nativeAd.Icon.Drawable);
                adView.IconView.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
            }

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(nativeAd.Price))
            {
                adView.PriceView.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
            }
            else
            {
                adView.PriceView.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
                ((TextView)adView.PriceView).Text = nativeAd.Price;
            }

            if (nativeAd.Store == null)
            {
                adView.StoreView.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;
            }
            else
            {
                adView.StoreView.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
                ((TextView)adView.StoreView).Text = nativeAd.Store;
            }

            if (nativeAd.StarRating == null)
            {
                adView.StarRatingView.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;
            }
            else
            {
                ((RatingBar)adView.StarRatingView).Rating = nativeAd.StarRating.FloatValue();
                adView.StarRatingView.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
            }

            if (nativeAd.Advertiser == null)
            {
                adView.AdvertiserView.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;
            }
            else
            {
                ((TextView)adView.AdvertiserView).Text = nativeAd.Advertiser;
                adView.AdvertiserView.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
            }

            // This method tells the Google Mobile Ads SDK that you have finished populating your
            // native ad view with this native ad.
            adView.SetNativeAd(nativeAd);
        }
    }

    public class UnifiedNativeAdLoadedListener : AdListener, UnifiedNativeAd.IOnUnifiedNativeAdLoadedListener
    {
        public void OnUnifiedNativeAdLoaded(UnifiedNativeAd ad)
        {
            OnNativeAdLoaded?.Invoke(this, ad);
        }

        public EventHandler<UnifiedNativeAd> OnNativeAdLoaded { get; set; }
    }

}
```

XML to handle received Ad Content -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.gms.ads.formats.UnifiedNativeAdView android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
        app:cardCornerRadius="12dp">
 
        <LinearLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="#FFFFFF">
 
            <AbsoluteLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1">
 
                <com.google.android.gms.ads.formats.MediaView
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/ad_media"/>
                
 
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:text="Ad"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:background="#FFCC66"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:padding="4dp" />
            </AbsoluteLayout>
 
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="5dp">
 
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:gravity="fill_horizontal">
 
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">
 
                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/ad_app_icon"
                            android:layout_width="40dp"
                            android:layout_height="40dp"
                            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                            android:paddingEnd="5dp"
                            android:paddingRight="5dp"/>
 
                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:orientation="vertical">
 
                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/ad_headline"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:textColor="#0000FF"
                                android:text="Join the dark side!"
                                android:textSize="16sp"
                                android:textStyle="bold" />
 
                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:orientation="horizontal">
 
                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/ad_advertiser"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:gravity="bottom"
                                    android:textSize="14sp"
                                    android:text="Google"
                                    android:textColor="#222222"
                                    android:textStyle="bold"/>
 
                                <RatingBar
                                    android:id="@+id/ad_stars"
                                    style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:isIndicator="true"
                                    android:numStars="5"
                                    android:stepSize="0.5"
                                    android:rating="4" />
                            </LinearLayout>
 
                        </LinearLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>
 
                    <TextView
                        android:textColor="#555555"
                        android:id="@+id/ad_body"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nis."
                        android:textSize="12sp" />
                </LinearLayout>
 
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:id="@+id/ad_store"
                           android:text="Google Play"
                        android:textColor="#222222"
                         android:textSize="12sp" />
 
                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/ad_call_to_action"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_margin="0dp"
                        android:text="INSTALL"
                        android:textSize="12sp" />
 
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/ad_price"
                        android:text="$ 3.49"
                        android:textColor="#222222"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:textSize="12sp" />
 
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</com.google.android.gms.ads.formats.UnifiedNativeAdView>
```

I have referred this article for Android Implmentation -

https://startdebugging.net/2019/09/admob-native-ads-in-xamarin-forms-android/

I tried this in IOS and my code so far is this -

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(AdmobNativeAd), typeof(AdMobNativeAdRenderer))]
namespace xxxx.iOS.Renderers
{
    public class AdMobNativeAdRenderer :  ViewRenderer<AdmobNativeAd, NativeExpressAdView>
    {
        NativeExpressAdView mAdView;
        bool viewOnScreen;

        // public AdMobNativeAdRenderer(Context context) : base() { }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<AdmobNativeAd> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.NewElement == null)
                return;

            if (e.OldElement == null)
            {
                CreateAdView(this);
            }
        }
                private void CreateAdView(AdMobNativeAdRenderer renderer)
                {

                    if (Element == null) return;

                    var loader = new AdLoader(
                       "ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                        GetVisibleViewController(),
                        new AdLoaderAdType[] { AdLoaderAdType.UnifiedNative },
                        new AdLoaderOptions[] {
                    new NativeAdViewAdOptions {PreferredAdChoicesPosition = AdChoicesPosition.TopRightCorner}
                        });

                    var request = Request.GetDefaultRequest();
                    request.TestDevices = new string[] { Request.SimulatorId };

                   
                    if (adView == null) return;

                    try
                    {
                        loader.Delegate = new MyAdLoaderDelegate(renderer);
                        loader.LoadRequest(request);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
                    }

                    Debug.WriteLine("Loading: " + loader.IsLoading);
                }

                private UIViewController GetVisibleViewController()
                {
                    var windows = UIApplication.SharedApplication.Windows;
                    foreach (var window in windows)
                    {
                        if (window.RootViewController != null)
                        {
                            return window.RootViewController;
                        }
                    }
                    return null;
                }
```

I couldn't figure out how to create UI similar to xml doc above for IOS and link it with the delegate.

Also, I would like to mention I am using Visual studio 2019 Windows for this project.

Comment: Hi, could you share some code of Xamarin Forms and Android how to achieve that? This will be helpful to check for iOS.

Comment: Hi, I have uploaded my code in the Edit.

Comment: Okey, thanks for updating. If good ideas will update here later.

Comment: Hi, I found an article: https://montemagno.com/xamarinforms-google-admob-ads-in-ios/ Maybe it will be helpful, you could have a look at that when you have time.

Comment: Thank you for this! My questions is about Unified Native Ads (Native Advanced Ads) and the article is about adding Banner Ads.